# Move file to newly created subfolder

Tags: powershell

I have to move a file daily to a folder which is a month folder. When the new months comes than the script should identify the newly create folder (which I will create with different script) and start pushing files to that new folder. Now when the year changes the script should identify the folder with the new year and under that the subfolder for the month and push the file to that new subfolder.

Sorry if this sounds confusing. Need help I know how to move files to another folder using PowerShell but getting into that hierarchy is something I am not able to accomplish.

Comment: please show what you have tried so far. You can use Get-Date command to accomplish this task and it is very well documented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try Something like this :

```
$CurrentDate=get-date
$year, $month= $CurrentDate.Year, $CurrentDate.Month
$storagedir="c:\temp\$year\$month"

if (! (Test-Path $storagedir))
{
    New-Item -ItemType Directory $storagedir
}

Move-Item "C:\temp\dbhash.csv" $storagedir -Force
```

Comment: Thank you so very much. Any suggestions on how to get the month name I have tried $year, $month= $CurrentDate.Year, $CurrentDate.MonthNames but it didn't worked.

Comment: try this :  (Get-Culture).DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName($month)

Comment: thanks I did it already using other way. But the thing is when I ran this script again to move other file in the same subfolder it didn't worked as the subfolder will remain the same through out the month it should be able to move file in the same subfolder each day for that month.

Answer (score 0):

Never Mind Got it. Below is the final script that worked perfectly for me

```
$CurrentDate=get-date
$year = $CurrentDate.Year
$folderName = (Get-Date).tostring("dd-MM-yyyy-hh") 
$storagedir="C:\Users\$year\$folderName"
if (! (Test-Path $storagedir))
{
    New-Item -ItemType Directory $storagedir
    }
if (Test-Path $storagedir)
{

Move-Item "C:\Users" $storagedir -Force
}
```